# How do the scaling paramters of ViewBox.setLimits() work?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to limit how much a ViewBox can zoom in/out and how much it can be moved.
I know that I must use `setLimits()` and I've read the documentation here
https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setLimits

While the panning limits are pretty self evident, I can't really understand how the scaling limits work.
What's the unit of measure? Is it pixels? Percentage?

[image: A screenshot of the docs is handy]

I've reached a usable point with these values, but not understanding why is bugging me!

```
view.setLimits(xMin=-image.shape[0]*0.05, xMax=image.shape[0]*1.05,
               minXRange=100, maxXRange=2000,
               yMin=-image.shape[1]*0.05, yMax=image.shape[1]*1.05,
               minYRange=100, maxYRange=2000)
```

I think it's a more theoretical question than anything else, but in case you want to try some code, here it is

```
# import the necessary packages
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ImageItem import ImageItem
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.LinearRegionItem import LinearRegionItem
import requests
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui


image = cv2.imread('aggraffatura.jpg') # Change the picture here!
image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with GraphicsView widget
w = pg.GraphicsView()
w.show()
w.resize(image.shape[0]/2, image.shape[1]/2) # Depending on the picture you may not need to resize
w.setWindowTitle('Test')

view = pg.ViewBox()
view.setLimits(xMin=-image.shape[0]*0.05, xMax=image.shape[0]*1.05,
               minXRange=100, maxXRange=2000,
               yMin=-image.shape[1]*0.05, yMax=image.shape[1]*1.05,
               minYRange=100, maxYRange=2000)
w.setCentralItem(view)

## lock the aspect ratio
view.setAspectLocked(True)

## Add image item
item = ImageItem(image)
view.addItem(item)

## Add line item
line = LinearRegionItem()
view.addItem(line)

def mouseClicked(evt):
    pos = evt[0]
    print(pos)

proxyClicked = pg.SignalProxy(w.scene().sigMouseClicked, rateLimit=60, slot=mouseClicked)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the unit of measure? Is it pixels? Percentage?

**Short answer**: The unit of measure of scaling limits is the same as the panning limits.

**Long answer**:
In class *ViewBox*, method *setLimits* calls method *updateViewRange*, which update view range to match the target view range as closely as possible, given aspect ratio constraints. Inside *updateViewRange* method, there is a section which loop through both axis and set the max view range to the smaller of max view range (the max scaling limit) and the absolute difference of lower and upper bounds (i.e. max-min, the difference of panning limits) (If scaling limit is not given, than it will be set to the difference of panning limits). Since the two limits can be interchangeable, they should have the same unit of measure.
Only by checking the source code one can see that max range cannot be larger than bounds, if they are given. This piece of information should be added to the document.
Note: when you zoom in to the limit you are actually setting the view range to the minRange of scaling limit.

**Example**: Here I will use op's example to illustrate the concept. [Download this image and rename it to '500x500' to test the example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWOn3.jpg). On start you should see that the view range is set to maxRange(400px) which is the diameter of the green circle. By zooming in, you should see that the view range can never be smaller than the red circle, which is 100px in diameter. The panning limit is set to the shape of the image, i.e. 500 X 500px.

```py
# import the necessary packages
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ImageItem import ImageItem
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.LinearRegionItem import LinearRegionItem
import requests
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

# Name the image to 500x500
image = cv2.imread('500x500.jpg') # Change the picture here!
image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with GraphicsView widget
w = pg.GraphicsView()
w.show()
w.resize(image.shape[0], image.shape[1]) # Depending on the picture you may not need to resize
w.setWindowTitle('Test')

view = pg.ViewBox()
view.setLimits(xMin=0, xMax=image.shape[0],
               minXRange=100, maxXRange=400,
               yMin=0, yMax=image.shape[1],
               minYRange=100, maxYRange=400)
w.setCentralItem(view)

## lock the aspect ratio
view.setAspectLocked(True)

## Add image item
item = ImageItem(image)
view.addItem(item)

## Add line item
line = LinearRegionItem()
view.addItem(line)

def mouseClicked(evt):
    pos = evt[0]
    print(pos)

proxyClicked = pg.SignalProxy(w.scene().sigMouseClicked, rateLimit=60, slot=mouseClicked)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```